# Transaction "Failed", but it says "Although one or more errors occured [Out of gas] contract execution completed"

Tags: out-of-gas

I sent ETH with MetaMask and it seems that the transaction ran out of gas. However, the ETH is gone. They don't show up in my wallet anymore. The receiving party says, that they did not get it either.

Can anyone help me finding out, where the ETH is?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x02280316497855dd69c8e0713e6bff61cf43d906431efb5364346058424adfc5

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The status of the transaction has

> TxReceipt Status: Fail

It means the whole transaction has failed and it was reversed immediately. The ether sent was returned to your account (minus ether used to pay the gas cost of the transaction).

Some intermediate operations (usually called "internal transactions") were sucessful but since the whole transaction was reversed they were also reversed, it is like they never happened.

Some wallets have problems with reversed trasaction check with your wallet support, in case of doubt use several block explorers to check your balance.

Answer (score 1):

The Ether is not gone, all of it was sent to contract 0xb1690C08E213a35Ed9bAb7B318DE14420FB57d8C

Then the 0xb1690C08E213a35Ed9bAb7B318DE14420FB57d8C have sent 0.027417213541666667 ETH to contract 0x9f78C5796230BfE85CB42b3cE9BDD9ae5Bb76714 and then this contract have sent 0.000029238211805555 ETH to contract 0x8380bA69401e903f099c9FDd8B4AA34772b83aA3

I suppose the reminder is still at 0xb1690C08E213a35Ed9bAb7B318DE14420FB57d8C, maybe its is some tx fee.

If you look at Internal Tx tab on Etherscan, it will tell you the whole story.

The error probably was triggered by contract 0x8380bA69401e903f099c9FDd8B4AA34772b83aA3 because it is way too low 2300 gas to do something.

Then since the execution reverted, the ether was returned back to you, and only Tx fees were taken from your account.